# SQL query to Return latest entry per user in mysql utilizing two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE..  I am working with two tables.  The "Answer" users are linking to only utilizes one table.  I need to return the latest entry utilizing RELATED tables.  I have not found a solution which does this.

I'm working on a time clock.  I have two tables in my db called employees and punches..  The punches table has a field called 'emp_id' which relates to the 'id' field in the employees table.  I'm trying to figure out a SQL query which will return the latest entry for each employee (Their current status, whether they are currently clocked IN, OUT, BREAK, etc.)

The answers I have found (and are referenced in the comments) are not pulling the info from two tables, just one.

So far, I have the following, but this only returns the first punch for each employee.  I am trying to return the latest punch instead.

```
    SELECT CONCAT(employees.first, ' ', 'employees.last) AS name, punches.id, punches.date, TIME_FORMAT(punches.tistamp, '%H:%i') AS time
FROM employees, punches
WHERE punches.emp_id=employees.id
GROUP BY emp_id
ORDER BY emp_id DESC
```

The punches table has an 'id' field which auto increments, so essentially I am looking for the max punches.id for each employee.

Comment: Use `Join` instead of a `Where` and show desired output in a table format,

Comment: Add both tables schema

Comment: I tried changing WHERE to JOIN, but received a mysql error.

Comment: I found that this works.. "SELECT m1.* FROM punches m1 LEFT JOIN punches m2 ON (m1.emp_id = m2.emp_id AND m1.id < m2.id) WHERE m2.id IS NULL", but it cannot figure out how to get the info from the related table with this..

Comment: Why the group by clause?  What are you aggregating?

Comment: I'm trying to create a webpage(php) to easily show the current status of employees (wheather they are clocked in, on break, or clocked out)  I'm using GROUP BY to only show the one record per employee.

Comment: I have found a query that works. Here it is if anyone comes accross this..

Comment: SELECT  p.emp_id, CONCAT(e.last, ', ', e.first) AS name, p.status, DATE_FORMAT(p.tistamp, '%d/%m/%Y') AS date, TIME_FORMAT(p.tistamp, '%H:%i') AS time
FROM punches p, employees e
WHERE p.emp_id=e.id
AND p.id = (SELECT MAX(p.id) FROM punches p WHERE e.id=p.emp_id) ORDER BY e.last ASC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this code works..

```
SELECT p.emp_id, CONCAT(e.last, ', ', e.first) AS name, p.status, DATE_FORMAT(p.tistamp, '%d/%m/%Y') AS date, TIME_FORMAT(p.tistamp, '%H:%i') AS time FROM punches p, employees e WHERE p.emp_id=e.id AND p.id = (SELECT MAX(p.id) FROM punches p WHERE e.id=p.emp_id) ORDER BY e.last ASC
```